# Personal Gmail statistics

Tags: gmail, statistics

I want to view my personal Gmail statistics.

1. How many emails I am sending or receiving on average in one day/month/week?
2. How many emails I am sending to a specific contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Google has introduced [GMail Meter](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2012/04/know-your-gmail-stats-using-gmail-meter.html)

- **Volume Statistics** show you the number of important and starred
  messages, the number of people who sent you emails, and more. Volume
  statistics can be very useful in determining how you are using email
  efficiency tools like Priority Inbox.

[image]

- **Daily Traffic** gives you an estimate of when you receive messages and
  when you send them during a given month. For example, in the graph
  below you can see how the peaks in my “Sent” curve indicates that I
  write emails in spurts.

[image]

And more options, see the blog post for details.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [Account Activity](https://www.google.com/settings/activity/), where you can see your entire Google monthly activity, including Gmail stats.

> For example, my most recent Account Activity report told me that I sent 5 percent more email than the previous month and received 3 percent more.

[Source](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/03/giving-you-more-insight-into-your.html).

> Google Account Activity creates monthly reports on your usage of Google products. Depending on which products you use, you can see *how many emails you've sent, who your most popular contacts are*, what searches you've performed, or what computers you've used to sign in.

(Emphasis by me.)

[Source](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2478305).

Answer (score 2):

[mail-trends](http://code.google.com/p/mail-trends/) seems to correspond to what you want. You'll have to use Python and some other dependancies.

Comment: Mail trends has been forked on Github and now has a new maintainer:
https://github.com/npinto/mail-trends

Answer (score 2):

If and when it is finally release, [Xobni for Gmail](http://www.xobni.com/waitinglist/gmailbeta/) promises to be an easier way of doing this.

Their Outlook version has all kinds of statistics in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Gmail Stats](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/articles/gmail-stats.html).

I'll add other interesting graphs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ruby-gmail](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail) if Ruby is your thing.